# Gradle test task doesn't produced any output files

Tags: java, gradle

I have been working on an Ant to Gradle migration, I have the primary build process working as it should and am now working on the test compilation and execution phase however I am having an issue with the test compilation task.
The testClasses task executes without error but there are no .class files being produced, its as if the testCompileJava task isn't able to find either the source or the output directories it needs.
 build.gradle below:

```
//Build for XXXXX.com
apply plugin: 'java'

apply from: 'build-properties.gradle'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    sourceCompatibility = compile_source
    targetCompatibility = compile_target
 }


//SourceSets
sourceSets{
    main{
        java{
            srcDir     src_dir
            }
        }
    test{
        java{
            srcDirs test_src_dir
            }
            output.classesDir  test_dir
        }
}



task generate_scripts(type: GradleBuild){
    buildFile = 'build-db.gradle'
    tasks = ['generate_scripts']
}
task test_init(type: GradleBuild){
    buildFile = 'build-tests.gradle'
    tasks = ['test_init']
}


task init_build{
    description 'Initialises the build environment'
    init_build.mustRunAfter clean
    doFirst{
    mkdir ( build_dir)
    mkdir ( build_apps_dir)
    mkdir ( build_classes_dir)
    mkdir ( build_lib_dir)
    mkdir ( build_lib_license_dir)
    mkdir ( build_log_dir)
    mkdir ( build_javadoc_dir)
    }

    doLast{
    //Copy the web files (jsp, css images, web.xml, etc)
    copy {
        from ("${src_web_dir}/resources", exclude: '**/*.db' )
        into build_dir }
    copy {
        from src_web_inf_dir
        into build_web_inf_dir }
    copy {
        from config_dir + '/c3p0-config.xml'
        into  build_classes_dir }
    copy {
        from config_dir + '/ehcache.xml'
        into  build_classes_dir }
    copy {
        from config_dir + '/ESAPI.properties'
        into  build_classes_dir }
    copy {
        from config_dir + '/validation.properties'
        into  build_classes_dir }
    copy {
        from src_dir + '/com/XXXX/jnlp/servlet/resources/strings.properties'
        into  build_classes_dir + '/com/XXXX/jnlp/servlet/resources/' }
    copy {
        from lib_dir + '/font'
        into build_classes_dir }

    //= copy server dependencies
    copy {
        from lib_compile_dir
        into build_lib_dir }
    copy {
        from lib_runtime_dir
        into build_lib_dir }

    // copy lib licenses
    copy {
        from lib_license_dir
        into build_lib_license_dir}
    }
}

task copyUpgradeScripts(dependsOn:[generate_scripts, init_build]){
    //        <!-- copy scripts to upgrade directories -->
            doFirst{
                  copy{
                from "${database_dir}/setup-data.sql" 
                into "${mssql_upgrade_dir}" 
                }
            copy{
                from ("${database_dir}/XXXXX-mssql-nodrop.sql")
                {
                    rename
                    {
                        String fileName -> "${mssql_upgrade_dir}/XXXXX-nodrop.sql"
                    }
                }
                into "${mssql_upgrade_dir}"
                }

            }

    //init_build.mustRunAfter generate_scripts
}

 compileJava {
    description 'Compile the source code'
    source sourceSets.main.java
    destinationDir =  file(build_classes_dir)
    options.debug  = compile_debug
    options.deprecation = compile_deprecation
    classpath = compileJava.classpath
    options.encoding = compile_encoding

    //Copy application resources
    doLast{
        copy {
            from config_dir
            into build_classes_dir
            }
        //Copy hibernate xml files
        copy {
            from src_dir 
            include '**/*.hbm.xml'
            into build_classes_dir
            }
        // Copy any image files
        println 'Begin copy images'
        copy {
            from src_dir 
            include '**/*.png'
            include '**/*.gif'
            include '**/*.jpeg'
            include '**/*.jpg'
            into build_classes_dir

            }
    }
    doLast{
        delete "${build_classes_dir}/com/XXXX/jnlp/jardiff/resources"
    }
}
compileJava.dependsOn init_build


       //**Here lay the issue**//

     compileTestJava{
    compileTestJava.dependsOn(test_init,compileJava) 
    println "JAVAHOME" +  System.getProperty( "java.home" )
    source sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs
    destinationDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir
    options.debug =  'true'
    options.deprecation =  compile_deprecation
    classpath = configurations.testCompile
    options.encoding = compile_encoding
    }


clean{
    description 'Removes all generated files'
    delete "${build_dir}"
    delete "${dist_dir}"
    delete "${test_dir}"
}



//Dependencies

dependencies{

  compile      fileTree(dir: lib_compile_dir, include: '*.jar')   
  compile      fileTree(dir: lib_provided_dir, include: '*.jar')
  compile      fileTree(dir: lib_dir + '/compile-applet', include: '*.jar')



  testCompile  fileTree(dir:lib_test_dir, include:'*.jar')     
  testCompile  fileTree(dir: lib_build_dir, include: '*.jar')
  testCompile  files(build_classes_dir)
  testCompile  configurations.compile        

  testRuntime  configurations.compile            
  testRuntime  fileTree(dir:lib_test_dir, include:'*.jar', exclude:'ant.jar')
  testRuntime  fileTree(dir: lib_build_dir, include: '*.jar', exclude:'ant.jar')
  testRuntime  files(build_classes_dir)
  testRuntime  fileTree(dir:lib_runtime_dir, include:'*.jar')
  testRuntime  files(test_dir)
  testRuntime  files(build_dir)

 }

}
```

Comment: For anyone who is having this same issue I found my error was in the configuration of the compileTestJava task, original post edited to reflect changes.